# AngularJS: Pass arithmetic operators to ng-value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS.

I am starting with simple calculator application which does operation `+` `-` `*` and `/`.

Module: `myMdl.js`

```
var ap = angular.module("myMdl", [])
```

Controller: `myCtrl1.js`

```
ap.controller("myCtrl1", function($scope) {
  $scope.Number1 = "1";
  $scope.Number2= "2";
});
```

View: `Calculator.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<h1> Calculator Application </h1>

<div ng-app="myMdl" ng-controller="myCtrl1">
    <br>
    Select Operator:
    <ul>
     <input type="radio" ng-model="Mdloperator" name="operator" ng-value="+" checked/>  + <br>
     <input type="radio" ng-model="Mdloperator" name="operator" ng-value="-" />  -  <br>
     <input type="radio" ng-model="Mdloperator" name="operator" ng-value="*"/>  *  <br>
     <input type="radio" ng-model="Mdloperator" name="operator" ng-value="/"/>  /  <br>
    </ul>               
    Enter Value's: 
    <ul>
        <input type="number" ng-model="Number1" value="{{Number1}}" /> <br>
        <input type="number" ng-model="Number2" value="{{Number2}}" /> <br>
    </ul>
    Result: <br>
    <ul>
        <input type="number" ng-model="result" value="{{Number1 + Mdloperator + Number2}}" placeholder="Result"/>
    </ul>
</div>

<script src="myMdl.js"></script>
<script src="myCtrl1.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) [`ngValue`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue) expects expression, but simple `+` sign is not a valid expression, it will give errors in the console, that is why you have to work with strings, when populating your `type="radio"` elements.

2) As you are dealing with strings, you have to use [`$parse` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse) to evaluate this string into result.

3) There is no need to use [`ngModel`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) together with `value="{{...}}"` on the `input type="number"` elements.

See example here:

```js
angular.module("myMdl", [])
.controller("myCtrl1", function($scope, $parse) {
  var ctrl = this;
  
  ctrl.Mdloperator = '/';
  ctrl.Number1 = 1;
  ctrl.Number2 = 2;
  
  ctrl.getValue = function(val){
   return angular.isString(val) ? $parse(val)($scope) : val;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>


<h1> Calculator Application </h1>

<div ng-app="myMdl" ng-controller="myCtrl1 as $ctrl">
    <br>
    Select Operator:
    <ul>
     <input ng-repeat-start="op in ['+', '-', '*', '/'] track by $index" type="radio" ng-model="$ctrl.Mdloperator" name="operator" ng-value="op" />  {{::op}} <br ng-repeat-end/>
    </ul>               
    Enter Value's: 
    <ul>
        <input type="number" ng-model="$ctrl.Number1"  /> <br>
        <input type="number" ng-model="$ctrl.Number2" /> <br>
    </ul>
    Result: <br>
    <ul>
        <input type="number" value="{{$ctrl.getValue($ctrl.Number1 + $ctrl.Mdloperator + $ctrl.Number2)}}" placeholder="Result"/>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies at `value="{{Number1 + Mdloperator + Number2}}"`
javascript converts a number datatypes to string when you use `+` operator on integers with string.

One of the solutions can be:

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1> Calculator Application </h1>
            <div ng-app="myMdl" ng-controller="myCtrl1">
                <br/>
                <span>Select Operator:</span>
                <ul>
                    <input type="radio" ng-model="Mdloperator" name="operator" ng-value="+" checked/>+<br/>
                     <input type="radio" ng-model="Mdloperator" name="operator" ng-value="-" />-<br/>
                     <input type="radio" ng-model="Mdloperator" name="operator" ng-value="*"/>*<br/>
                     <input type="radio" ng-model="Mdloperator" name="operator" ng-value="/"/>/<br/>
                </ul>               
                <span>Enter Value's:</span>     
                <ul>
                    <input type="number" ng-model="Number1" value="{{Number1}}" /> <br/>
                    <input type="number" ng-model="Number2" value="{{Number2}}" /> <br/>
                </ul>
                <span>Result:</span><br/>
                <div ng-switch="Mdloperator">
                   <span ng-switch-when="+">{{Number1 + Number2}}</span>
                   <span ng-switch-when="-">{{Number1 - Number2}}</span>
                   <span ng-switch-when="*">{{Number1 * Number2}}</span>
                   <span ng-switch-when="/">{{Number1 / Number2}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <script src="myMdl.js"></script>
            <script src="myCtrl1.js"></script>
        </body>
</html>
```